# Same Fragment Should Appear one below another according to the Number Selected in Spinner. HOW?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a Small Fragment with three EditText and i have a Spinner with 1,2,3 as options in It.

What i want to do is that, when i select '1' from the Spinner, i want my fragment to appear below the spinner in same Activity.

And when i select '2' in Spinner, the same Fragment Should Appear Twice one below another in the same Activity and similarly for when i select '3' from Spinner.

**HERE IS THE JAVA CODE**

```
    package com.globaltech2u.databaseapp1;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Spinner spinner;
    private String bookno[] = {"#","1","2","3","4"};
    private ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;

    private EditText editText,editText2,editText3;
    private CheckBox checkBox;
    private Button button;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private Database mySQLiteOpenHelper;
    private Fragment fragment;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et1);
        editText2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et2);
        editText3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et3);
        checkBox = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cb1);
        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.booknoselectspinner);

        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, bookno);
        spinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);


        mySQLiteOpenHelper = new Database(this, "bookrecord", null, 1);
        db = mySQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();



        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String bookname = editText.getText().toString();
                String bookno = editText2.getText().toString();
                String issuedate = editText3.getText().toString();
                String query = "insert into bookrecord(bookname,bookno,issuedate) values('"+bookname+"','"+bookno+"','"+issuedate+"')";
                Log.e("query",query);
                db.execSQL(query);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


        final FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        final FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int i, long id) {

                for (int j=0;j<=i;j++){
                    BookentryFragment bookentryFragment = new BookentryFragment();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, bookentryFragment);

                }
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });



    }
}
```

**HERE IS THE MAIN ACTIVITY XML FILE**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Select No. of Books Issued"
        android:id="@+id/tv4"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="19dp"
        />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/booknoselectspinner"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv4"
        >

    </Spinner>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/FM1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv4"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Save Record"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/FM1"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**HERE IS THE FRAGMENT FILE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border">


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/et1"
        android:hint="Enter Book Name"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/booknoselectspinner"
        />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/et2"
        android:hint="Enter Book No."
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/et1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/et3"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:hint="Select Issue Date"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/et2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />
    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Remind me to Return"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/cb1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/et3"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />



</RelativeLayout>
```

**LET ME KNOW IF I SHOULD ATTACH SOMETHING ELSE**

**I TRIED TO USE WHILE LOOP BUT THE APP CRASHES. PLEASE HELP
THANK YOU**

***I tried it with this Layout Inflater Code.***

```
FrameLayout item = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.FM1);
View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_bookentry, null);
item.addView(child);
```

It adds the Fragment once when i open the Activity.

But when i select 2 from the spinner, Nothing Happens.

I am using Switch Case for this Purpose

```
switch (i) {
                case 0:
                    FrameLayout item = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.FM1);
                    View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_bookentry, null);
                    item.addView(child);
                    break;

                case 1:
                    FrameLayout item2 = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.FM1);
                    View child2 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_bookentry, null);
                    item2.addView(child2);
                    FrameLayout item3 = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.FM1);
                    View child3 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_bookentry, null);
                    item3.addView(child3);
                    break;

                case 2:
                    FrameLayout item4 = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.FM1);
                    View child4 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_bookentry, null);
                    item4.addView(child4);
                    FrameLayout item5 = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.FM1);
                    View child5 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_bookentry, null);
                    item5.addView(child5);
                    FrameLayout item6 = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.FM1);
                    View child6 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_bookentry, null);
                    item6.addView(child6);
                    break;
            }
```

Comment: You should use a custom view here, not a fragment.

Comment: Like use List View and Customize it???

Comment: Better option would be to inflate the xml using the `LayoutInflator` and adding it using `addView`.

Comment: Ok. I will try that. Thanks a Lot.

Comment: I have updated the Post please check it

Answer (score 0):

1. Make the `FrameLayout` a class object, and initialize it using `(FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.FM1);` only once, outside the `switch` statement.
2. In each of your `case` blocks, add this piece of code in the beginning:

   if(item.getChildCount()>0){
       item.removeAllViews();
   }

EDIT:  Your spinner's `onItemSelected` would be something like:

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int i, long id) {
    item.removeAllViews();
    for (int j=0;j<=i;j++){
        View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragmentXML, null);
        item.addView(v);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not Working for me

Comment: Found a Workaround with your help. Thanks

Comment: This helped in a way but i figured out my own way and posted it in thread